# Insert collect_set values into Elasticsearch with PIG

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, apache-pig

I have a HIVE table which contains 3 columns- "id"(String), "booklist"(Array of String), and "date"(string) with the following data:

```
----------------------------------------------------
id | booklist            | date
----------------------------------------------------
1  | ["Book1" , "Book2"] | 2017-11-27T01:00:00.000Z
2  | ["Book3" , "Book4"] | 2017-11-27T01:00:00.000Z
```

When trying to insert into Elasticsearch with this PIG script

```
-------------------------Script begins------------------------------------------------
 SET hive.metastore.uris 'thrift://node:9000';
 REGISTER hdfs://node:9001/library/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.0.0.jar;
 DEFINE HCatLoader org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
 DEFINE EsStore org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage(
 'es.nodes = elasticsearch.service.consul',
 'es.port = 9200',
 'es.write.operation = upsert',
 'es.mapping.id = id',
 'es.mapping.pig.tuple.use.field.names=true'
 );

hivetable = LOAD 'default.reading' USING HCatLoader();
hivetable_flat = FOREACH hivetable 
                 GENERATE 
                   id AS id, 
                   booklist as bookList,
                   date AS date;
STORE hivetable_flat INTO 'readings/reading' USING EsStore();
 -------------------------Script Ends------------------------------------------------
```

When running above, i got an error saying:

```
ERROR 2999:Unexpected internal error. Found unrecoverable error [ip:port] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse [bookList]; Bailing out..
```

1. Can anyone shed any light on how to parse ARRAY of STRING into ES and get above to work?

Thank you!